# how to access evet data inside usestate hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to use panResponder to manage users gesture on the screen and to change volume of the Video Player by sliding to top and bottom on the screen.
now I am trying to access event type when accessing prev data inside state in order to set new state, but I get null every time I access it.

```
onPanResponderGrant: (event, gestureState) => {
        setPanResponderData(data => {
          console.log('event.nativeEvent', event.nativeEvent) // this will return null
          return {
            ...data, 
            recordHandleY: [],
            recordHandleX: [],
            startX: event.nativeEvent.pageX,
            startY: event.nativeEvent.pageY 
          };
        });
      }
```

this is setPanResponderData:

```
const [panResponderData, setPanResponderData] = useState({
    startX: 0, 
    startY: 0, 
    recordHandleX: [], 
    recordHandleY: [], 
    moveYData: 0, 
    moveXData: 0
  });
```

and this is the main panResponder code:

```
const panResponder = React.useMemo(
    () => PanResponder.create({
      // Ask to be the responder:
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) =>
        false,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) =>
        true,

      onPanResponderGrant: (event, gestureState) => {
        setPanResponderData(data => {
          console.log('event.nativeEvent', event.nativeEvent)
          return {
            ...data, 
            recordHandleY: [],
            recordHandleX: [],
            startX: event.nativeEvent.pageX,
            startY: event.nativeEvent.pageY 
          }
        });
        SystemSetting.getVolume().then(volume => setVolume(volume))
      },
      onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
        if (panResponderData.recordHandleY.length < 10) {
          setPanResponderData(data => {
            return {
              ...data,
              recordHandleY: [...data.recordHandleY, evt.nativeEvent.pageY],
              recordHandleX: [...data.recordHandleX, evt.nativeEvent.pageX],
              moveYData: panResponderData.startY - evt.nativeEvent.pageY,
              moveXData: evt.nativeEvent.pageX - panResponderData.startX
            }
          })
        }
        const height = width * 210 / 375;
        let soundDataY = (panResponderData.startY + 30 - gestureState.moveY) / (height)
        
        if (panResponderData.recordHandleY.length === 10) {
          if (Math.abs(panResponderData.recordHandleY[9] - panResponderData.recordHandleY[0]) > Math.abs(panResponderData.recordHandleX[9] - panResponderData.recordHandleX[0])) {
            if (Math.abs(panResponderData.moveYData) > 5) {
              if (Math.abs(soundDataY) <= 1 && panResponderData.startX > width / 2) {
                SystemSetting.setVolume(soundDataY);
                if (soundDataY > 0) {
                  setVolume(soundDataY * 100);
                } else {
                  setVolume(0);
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      onPanResponderTerminationRequest: (evt, gestureState) =>
        true,
      onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {
      },
      onPanResponderTerminate: (evt, gestureState) => {
      },
      onShouldBlockNativeResponder: (evt, gestureState) => {
        return true;
      }
    })
  );
```

what should I do?

Comment: where is onPanResponderGrant called ? if you console log event or event.nativeEvent before setting state do you have anything ?

Comment: @Ivo yes I will get the data before setState